# issueCommand REBOOT does not work. How do I resolve this?

Tags: android, android-management-api

I've been looking through stackoverflow for some answers, most of them saying that this issue has already been resolved, yet here I am still facing the issue.

My code is as such:

```
androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().issueCommand(
    name='enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/devices/34f0xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    body={
        "type": "REBOOT",
        "duration": "30s"
    }
).execute()
```

and I get a response body of

```
{'metadata': {'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.android.devicemanagement.v1.Command',
  'createTime': '2020-06-12T06:22:01.429Z',
  'duration': '30s',
  'type': 'REBOOT',
  'userName': 'enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/users/108xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
 'name': 'enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/devices/34f0xxxxxxxxxxxx/operations/1591xxxxxxxxxx'}
```

Anybody knows whats the error? Or what am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There was probably a delay when completing execution of command. The `duration` specifies how long for which the command is valid. You could try extending the duration of the command to maybe a day and observe if the device reboots.

```
androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().issueCommand( name='enterprises/LCxxxxxxxx/devices/34f0xxxxxxxxxxxx', body={ "type": "REBOOT", "duration":"86400"} ).execute()
```

If the command never gets completed you can cancel it using this [API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices.operations/cancel), passing the operation name.

```
androidmanagement.enterprises().devices().operations().cancel(name="enterprises/LC0xxxxxxx/devices/34f0xxxxxxxxxxxx/operations/123456789012").execute()
```